# Javascript - handling keypresses in order?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple "onKeyUp" Javascript routine that is supposed to handle adding dashes to an input field to format a phone number, turning "1234567890" into "123-456-7890".   However, if the user types too fast the routine apparently doesn't fire, or the event gets lost, I'm not sure.   But in that case, the dashes don't get inserted.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?   Here's the routine:

```
function(event, field) {
    //  Don't add dashes if user pressed backspace
    if (event.keyCode != 8 ) {
        if (field.value.length == 3 || field.value.length == 7) {
            field.value = field.value + "-";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: if you can provide a jsbin or fiddle I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: What if the 3rd character is a dash?

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin called maskedInput or some such which does something like this that I sued a while back.  From my meory of how it worked they made the changes and then altered the cursros position, so maybe that is the missing step?

Comment: Works okay for me in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/brcSL/

Comment: Instead of looking for the specific character length, reformat the value on every key up. e.g. If field.value.length >= 7 then do add hyphen to value. If you don't mind latency you could add a setTimeout of a short time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/derir/1/edit)

```
var dashes = function(event, field) {
  if (event.keyCode != 8 ) {
    var arr = field.value.split(''),
        l = arr.length;
    if(l > 2 && arr[3] != "-") arr.splice(3, 0, "-");
    if(l > 6 && arr[7] != "-") arr.splice(7, 0, "-");
    field.value = arr.join('');
  }
};

var input = document.getElementById('in');

input.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
  dashes(event, input);
});
```